# How to Pass the arguments inside http.Controller classes in odoo 8

Tags: python, odoo-8

I am trying to pass the input values to action_button_confirm which is confirm onchange of sale order.

```
@http.route('/approve/<path:token>', type='http', auth='none')
def sale_order(self, token, **kwargs):
    dbname = request.session._db
    registry = openerp.modules.registry.Registry(dbname)
    sale_id = http.request.env['sale.order'].sudo().search([('access_token', '=', token), ('state','=','draft')]).id
    with registry.cursor() as cr:
        http.request.env['sale.order'].action_button_confirm(sale_id,context=None)
```

I tried following scenarios

1. action_button_confirm(cr, openerp.SUPERUSER_ID, sale_id)
2. action_button_confirm(cr, uid, openerp.SUPERUSER_ID, sale_id)
3. action_button_confirm(cr, uid, openerp.SUPERUSER_ID, sale_id, contect=None)

The sale order confirm function is

```
def action_button_confirm(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
```

Answer (score 0):

try below solution:

```
sale_id = http.request.env['sale.order'].sudo().search([('access_token', '=', token), ('state','=','draft')])
sale_id.action_button_confirm()
```